# Type 'Headers' has no properties in common with type 'RequestOptionsArgs'?

Tags: angular, typescript

I just made two important upgrades to our Angular 4 application and build tools:

1. *@angular/core* `^4.1.3` => `^4.2.4` (and /http, /forms, etc)
2. *tslint* `^5.3.2` => `^5.4.3`

I have a Service which declares options like so:

```
@Injectable()
export class WorkOrderService {

    private headers: Headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    private options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions(this.headers);

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    /* Methods ... */
}
```

The above now no longer validates tslint, throwing the following error:

> error TS2559: Type 'Headers' has no properties in common with type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.

The source (@angular/http `interface.d.ts:43`) clearly allows for `Headers` as a `RequestOptionsArgs`:

```
/**
 * Interface for options to construct a RequestOptions, based on
 * [RequestInit](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#requestinit) from the Fetch spec.
 *
 * @experimental
 */
export interface RequestOptionsArgs {
    url?: string | null;
    method?: string | RequestMethod | null;
    /** @deprecated from 4.0.0. Use params instead. */
    search?: string | URLSearchParams | {
        [key: string]: any | any[];
    } | null;
    params?: string | URLSearchParams | {
        [key: string]: any | any[];
    } | null;
    headers?: Headers | null;
    body?: any;
    withCredentials?: boolean | null;
    responseType?: ResponseContentType | null;
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Update for 4.3 `HttpClient`

The new syntax to be compatible with [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http), introduced in angular 4.3, is:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";

private _options = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };
```

No more `RequestOptions`: parameters are added using the new immutable [`HttpParams`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) Map.

## Pre 4.3 / `Http`

I *just* noticed that `RequestOptions` now requires you to explicitly pass named options as an object, like:

```
headers: Headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
```

Comment: i have being running into similar issue , thank's for providing a solution

Comment: I think you mightve just needed brackets around your this.headers. new RequestOptions({this.headers});

Comment: @LLai Object destructuring doesn't work in this case because of the *this.*: `Argument of type '{ this: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'this' does not exist in type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.` but I had hoped so, as well.

Comment: I get HttpHeaders is not exported member of @angular/http, so from where are you importing HttpHeaders?

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain You're mixing paradigms. `HttpClient` doesn't come from `@angular/http`, it comes from `@angular/common/http`, which is where the rest are exported from as well. Updated the post.

Comment: Thank you so much @msanford, however I am getting this error Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'. Types 
 of property 'headers' are incompatible. Type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to type 'Headers'. Property 'forEach' 
 is missing in type 'HttpHeaders'.'   ,  when i am requesting like this  ---->this.http.post('http://localhost:56451/map',
              { "username": username, "password": password },
              this._options)

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain My pleasure. Again, you are mixing paradigms. I left `RequestOptionsArgs` in the _second_ part of the post because it no longer applies to `HttpClient`. The two complete code portions are equivalent. If you have a more complex case (such as setting request parameters) I'd post a new question.

Comment: yes, you are right, It necessitates a new question, I will post in a minute, however I am unclear about what paradigm what you are talking, any links as to where I can understand what you are referring to

Comment: @msanford, may you please help with following question as per your time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082492/how-to-send-post-request-using-http-from-angular-http

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain The paradigm meaning the new `HttpClient` (as of 4.3) or the old `Http` both for making REST requests. They are simply different libraries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158107/discussion-between-akshay-vijay-jain-and-msanford).

Comment: @msanford, sorry if I am making a mistake, but if you take a look at docs https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#add-the-ability-to-save-hero-details,           they have not used HttpClient,            but they have used Http instead to send requests -----> saying this because in another answer you have written Http was replaced by HttpClient, is that statement of yours still valid

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain Yes they probably have. It depends on which version of angular you are using. If it is after 4.3, I suggest using `HttpClient`, see https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: yes, you are right, here is document to show, Http is deprecated https://angular.io/api/http/Http

Comment: You saved my day. I was following the angular 2 syntax and getting the error. Your solution worked for angular 4