# Unable to do post request with HttpClient in angular using proxy config with solution

Tags: angular, httpclient

While I am trying to make post request in `HttpClient` getting the below error while same with rest client giving proper response. Same with angular 1 `$http` service is working as expected.

Tried multiple ways but neither post nor get method is working.
I am using angular-cli in which I have configured `proxy.config.json`

```
{
    "/api/*":{

        "target":"http://10.104.40.14:8290/my_app",
        "secure":false,
        "logLevel":"debug"
    }
}
```

// error code

```
 zone.js:2933 POST http://localhost:4200/api/security/login 401 (Unauthorized)
     <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
    </head>
    <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
    <p>Problem accessing /de_prp/error. Reason:
    <pre>    Unauthorized</pre></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my auth.service.ts file

```
    import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

   import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
        import { RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
        import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
        @Injectable()
        export class AuthService implements OnInit {
          constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

          ngOnInit(): void {

          }


          login(username, password, rememberMe) {
            console.log(username, password, rememberMe);

            //const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
            const body = JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password });
            const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            this.http.post("/api/security/login", body, { headers: headers }).subscribe(
              res => {
                console.log(res);
              },
              (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {

                console.log(err.error);
                console.log(err.name);
                console.log(err.message);
                console.log(err.status);
              }
            )
          }
          logout() {

            this.http.get("/api/auth/logout").subscribe(
              res => {
                console.log(res);
              },
              (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {

                console.log(err.error);
                console.log(err.name);
                console.log(err.message);
                console.log(err.status);
              }
            );
          }
        }
```

Solution: Finally resolve by entry in proxy.config.json given below
"pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""} so final json file is

```
{
    "/api/*":{

        "target":"http://10.104.40.14:8290/my_app",
        "secure":false,
        "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you use the developer tools in your browser and see if your requests are issued? You can see if your post request contains the headers you passed to it.

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:4200/api/security/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:4200
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
cache-control:must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
connection:close
content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
date:Tue, 24 Oct 2017 15:01:27 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
www-authenticate:Bearer
x-application-context:application:production:8290
X-Powered-By:Express

Comment: Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:61
Content-Type:text/plain

X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
view source
{username: "admin@example.com", password: "a123456"}
password
:
"a123456"
username
:
"admin@example.com"
Name

Comment: when I hit the get request it is giving proper response but not sure why post is creating an issue

Comment: It might be related to how the header of your post is formatted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write your post request this way:

```js
login(username, password, rememberMe)) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    //You can append here whatever you like in your headers;
    headers.append(username, password);

    options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions(headers);

    this.http.post(/api/security/login, options)
      .suscribe(res => res.json())
  }
```

The `401` is an error coming from the server handling the request. You need to see, if the server is getting the headers of your request or not.

Regarding your proxy config, you can do the following:

```js
{ "/api": { "target": "yourUrl.com", 
             "secure": false, 
             "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""} 
          }
}
```

*The `pathRewrite` option* will remove `api` from your url.

Comment: i am using httpClient so need to pass payload as username and password and header as const   headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'X-Requested-With' :'XMLHttpRequest' }); along with content-type. how to set mutliple header attributes

Comment: this is the angular 1 request header equest URL:http://localhost:5002/auth/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:5002
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Using the `RequestOptions` you can specify `{ 'X-Requested-With' :'XMLHttpRequest' } ` on your request. I edited my answer.

Comment: [ts] Type 'Headers' has no properties in common with type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
const headers: Headers

Comment: I edited the question based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728775/type-headers-has-no-properties-in-common-with-type-requestoptionsargs)

Comment: thanks just saved me. i was hitting request using proxy.config.json and hence it was giving 401 authorization error I just tried without it and it was working fine. also setting header is not required,could you please suggest how to manage proxy using proxy.config.json in angular-cli

Comment: finally got success with this {
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://url.com",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}

Comment: Great, you succeeded! I updated my answer. You can upvote and accept it.

Comment: hi after changing my webpack server port from 4200 to 5003 my api call again stop working and now getting 401 Unauthorization error and if i revert back port to 4200 it works fine

Comment: @RahulKumarJain, you can open a new SO ticket for it