# The type" Headers " has no properties in common with the type" RequestOptionsArgs

Tags: angular, typescript

I get the following error when I try to implement `headers`

[image]

`The type" Headers "has no properties in common with the type" RequestOptionsArgs "`

I was reading that apparently now we should use `HttpHeaders` but I can not implement it without avoiding the error

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacto',
  templateUrl: './contacto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacto.component.scss']
})
export class ContactoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: Http ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  sendMessage(){
   
    let url = `https://your-cloud-function-url/function`
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });

    params.set('to', 'user@example.com');
    params.set('from', 'you@yoursupercoolapp.com');
    params.set('subject', 'test-email');
    params.set('content', 'Hello World');

    return this.http.post(url, params, headers)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })

  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type 'Headers' has no properties in common with type 'RequestOptionsArgs'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728775/type-headers-has-no-properties-in-common-with-type-requestoptionsargs)

Comment: If I saw it but for more than I modify, it keeps generating the error, I do not understand why

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on the top answer for **Pre 4.3 / Http**?

Comment: I have added the answer to your code, so it will be easier for you to understand. please take a look and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

There are already few answers related to this.

[Difference between HTTP and HTTPClient in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129790/difference-between-http-and-httpclient-in-angular-4)

[Type 'Headers' has no properties in common with type 'RequestOptionsArgs'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728775/type-headers-has-no-properties-in-common-with-type-requestoptionsargs)

In your case (pre 4.3 angular version), working solution would be like below.

```
import {Headers, Http, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";

...

let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

...

return this.http.post(url, params, options)

...
```

Comment: This avoids the error in the code but it generates an error in console when executing the function:

Response to preflight request does not pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

I'm following this tutorial: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/angular4-transactional-email-with-cloud-functions-and-sendgrid/
(#Trigger from a Component)

Comment: @PacoZevallos maybe you are doing this from localhost, try using CORS plugin for chrome.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the official docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers):

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  }
};

return this.http.post(url, params, httpOptions)
    ...
```

This only works with the newer `HttpClient` implementation, which you should be able to easily switch to. Just import it like this:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and change your constructor's signature to this:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
```

Comment: The OP appears to be using the old `Http` (@angular/http) and not the new `HttpClient` (@angular/common/http)

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Good catch. Updated my post accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: This avoids the error in the code but it generates an error in console when executing the function:

Response to preflight request does not pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

I'm following this tutorial: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/angular4-transactional-email-with-cloud-functions-and-sendgrid/
(#Trigger from a Component)

Comment: @PacoZevallos The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` must be set on the server side, not on client side (I just copied them from your post). There seems to be a [more recent version of your tutorial](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/angular4-transactional-email-with-cloud-functions-and-sendgrid/). And [here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29548846/965834) that might give you a clue, but there's plenty of other online resources on it (e.g. [this one](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)).